# file.readlines() returns empty list

Tags: python, python-3.x, readlines

I was writing a code to make a json file using separate text files
my directory looks like this :-

```
locs
.    file1.txt
.    file2.txt
.    file3.txt
```

each file containing :-

```
[vector]
x=1286.45
y=298.11
z=-1047.22
```

my code :-

```
import json
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.withdraw()
folder_selected = filedialog.askdirectory()
mypath = folder_selected
onlyfiles = [f for f in listdir(mypath) if isfile(join(mypath, f))]
locdict = {}
for i in onlyfiles:
    with open (i,"r+") as  file1:
        lines = file1.readlines()
        print (lines)
    finalpos = [lines[1].removesuffix('x='), lines[2].removesuffix('y='), lines[3].removesuffix('z=')]
    locdict[name] =  i
    locdict[position] = finalpos
    file1.close()
    json_object = json.dumps(locdict)
    with open("sample.json", "w") as outfile:
        outfile.write(json_object)
```

when i run this code the output just says :-
[image]
any help wd be appreciated

Comment: `file1` is exhausted by the previous loop; there's nothing left to read once you call `file1.readlines()`.

Comment: You need to rewind the file after you've read through it the first time.

Comment: Or just get rid of the loop, which appears to be for debugging purposes only.

Comment: @chepner ur correct when i noticed readlines giving empty list i added that but i edited the question again its still giving me this error

Comment: Debug the (new) IndexError. Is `lines` what you expected? Does it have at least 4 items?

Comment: So does `print(lines)` actually output 4 lines?

Comment: Unrelated, you don't need `file1.close()`; the `with` statement has already closed the file, which is the reason to use a `with` statement in the first place.

Comment: printlines gives :-
[] for each file in the folder so if i printlines all the time it is like 
multiple times []

Comment: Also unrelated: `x=` et al. are *prefixes*, not suffixes; you're using the wrong method.

Comment: Either you are still exhausting the iterator before calling `readlines`, or you are reading from an empty file in the first place.

Comment: right its a prefix ;-;